# Trying to see questions with my tags fails

Tags: bug

So I have a link with my tags in my profile,it`s a quick way to return to the questions area.Many times when i click that link it gives me [image: this]

So what would be the cause?Is it on my end?

Comment: Although it has gotten a lot worse recently.